# How do I go about proving a bi-conditional statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: Homework Question]

I'm taking a discrete math class and am kind of confused on how to prove a bi-conditional statement. I understand that your supposed to first prove p implies q and then prove q implies p. However, I don't know how to practically apply that to the problems I've been given, so here I am. In the image link is the problem I'm having trouble with, if anyone could give me an example of working through something similar I would be grateful.

I've tried finding videos on proving bi-conditionals, but they always keep the problems they work rather simple and aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To prove a statement of the form $A \iff B$, you prove both $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$. So, in your case, you have to prove both the statement $\exists x[P(x) \lor Q(x)] \implies \exists x[P(x)] \lor \exists x[Q(x)]$ and the statement $\exists x[P(x)] \lor \exists x[Q(x)] \implies \exists x[P(x) \lor Q(x)]$.